# Do 360/3D videos in Chrome and YouTube app work on a phone without gyroscope?

Tags: gyroscope, nokia-5

I'd like to buy a new phone, I am considering a Nokia 5.3. I just noticed in its specification that it doesn't have a gyroscope. I wonder if embedded 3D/360 videos in Chrome ( and such videos in YouTube app ) would work on this phone ( + Google cardboard ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cardboard appears to require a gyroscope to operate.

From: https://support.google.com/cardboard/answer/6295046?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en

> **Check phone requirements**
>
> **Note:** If you get a device incompatible message, you may not have a phone fitted with a gyroscope.

Using a gyroscope improves the orientation position of the handset so that turning your head to the left 45 degrees actually feels similar to a 45 degree turn rather than something else.

Note that if you want to view 360 degree video and are willing to deal with swiping/dragging on the screen to move around, that shouldn't require a gyroscope.

I believe there are various apps which will play 360 degree video/3D? without a gyroscope, YMMV.

If you really want to do VR/AR type behavior with your phone (in Cardboard or not) you are better off getting a phone with a gyroscope.

As [ARCore](https://developers.google.com/ar) is Google's AR platform, and they list supported devices [here](https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/supported-devices#android_play) if you want to find something guaranteed to work.

Comment: Thank you very much! Nokia 5.3 is not even listed on ARCore.